# What's the proper way to provide help documentation for custom git commands?

Tags: git

If I write a script named `git-foo`, and drop it somewhere in my `PATH`, then I can run `git foo` to execute that script and can run `git foo --option argument` to pass command-line options and arguments to my script.

This syntactic sugar breaks down when trying to print help documentation, however.  I've made `git-foo --help` work, but if I run `git foo --help`, git does not forward `--help` to my script and instead tries to open a `man` page for `git-foo`.  I do not want this.  Is there any way to suppress this behavior for custom commands? (Ideally as a script author, but I'm willing to settle for a way to suppress this as a user.)

I suspect that I'm expected to generate a `man` page instead, but that seems rather onerous: then the script would need to be packaged with an extra file, and that extra file would need to be installed somewhere else, and then there would be more work to undo when uninstalling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're stuck.  Git intentionally implements `--help` via `man` pages in order to ensure that there is a single source of information (as opposed to having the man pages drift out of sync with embedded help output).

If you write a `man` page, you should be able to install it in a `man` directory at the same level as the `bin` directory into which you have installed your script.

Installing and removing a single additional file doesn't seem too bad.  Or you can just stick with

```
git-foo --help
```

and tell people to use that.

Comment: A more sensible approach to me would be to check if a man page exists and use that, otherwise pass `--help` through.  Or just always pass `--help` through to non-built-in, non-aliased commands, and let the custom command's `--help` handler open a man page if it wants to.